# UIAlertController, eliminate the animation on closing?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

Here's a simple action sheet,

```
let choice = UIAlertController(title: "Choose", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

choice.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.happyCamera() }))

choice.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Album", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.happyAlbum() }))

choice.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

somewhere?.present(choice, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

When the action sheet appears (note that present#animated is false) it just clicks on to the screen, no cheesey animation.

However, when the user taps one of the three choices, or, taps "off", the action sheet leaves the screen by using the cheesey animation.

(In 10.3 specifically, it slides downwards off the screen.)

Is there a way to turn off that exit animation?

[image]

---

## If you subclass UIAlertController...it doesn't work?

As DS suggests below, you could subclass UIAlertController.

However - strangely - it does nothing.  Here's a test

```
func _test() {
    
    let msg = SuperiorUIAlertController(
        title: "Hello", message: "Hello",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    msg.addAction(UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
        handler: nil))
    
    let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    win.rootViewController = vc
    win.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
    win.makeKeyAndVisible()    
    vc.present(msg, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

class SuperiorUIAlertController: UIAlertController {
    
    override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        
        print("You should see this! \(flag)")
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Indeed, the text "You should see this" **never appears**.

Comment: add dismiss in inside the handler

Comment: You are setted animation to false for Present not for Dismiss.

Comment: @Fattie see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but as of late 2017, **there is no way**.  Weird right?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same irritation - any chance you submitted a bug report to apple? If not, I'm considering doing so.

Comment: Ridiculous right?  @A.L.Strine  You know, I just didn't bother - Apple typically don't fix bugs for 5-10 years so why bother  :/

Answer (score 0):

The one more way you can Override dismiss method of viewController. If you don't wanna override other animations check animated flag value or make a flag in below method.

Make your AlertController globally

```
var choice = UIAlertController()
```

Make sure add this method in your viewController which you are presented alert

Dismiss presented alert without animation like below

```
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    self.choice.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: dismiss(animated:completion:) is one of the  instance method of UIViewController.check it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismissk

Comment: yep.The one way you can override it.i noted in my answer already.

Comment: strangely, this **does not work**.  the override is not even called, actually :/

Comment: it is true that `dismiss` **in the presenting view controller** is called, which I have always found very strange.

Comment: Make your alertController global & dismiss it in dismiss override method with animation false.it will work.

Comment: Note that it is incredibly impractical to do this, as you also have to pass around the completions.

Comment: I appreciate this works, @DSDharma, **thank you**.  However it flickers because you're interrupting the dismissal of the alert itself, and, the gray background.  Anyway thanks, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing UIAlertController like this:

```
class InstantCloseAlertController: UIAlertController {
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```